# Differentiation between const and non-const versions of methods in C++

Tags: c++, documentation, doxygen

I have a few questions regarding differentiation between const and non-const versions of methods in C++.

Example:

```
      MyObject* MyClass::objectReference()
const MyObject* MyClass::objectReference() const
```

My questions are:

1. Is there any way at all to differentiate between which version of the method is called manually? Or is it fully/completely automatic and if so what are the *precise* rules for determining which version is to be called?
2. Related to (1), if you cannot differentiate between calling the const vs the non-const version, it's therefore impossible to call one version of a method from the other to prevent duplication?
3. <del>How to create a link to one version or the other in the documentation of one of the methods using doxygen? (e.g. "const version of myMethod()." or "non-const version of myMethod().")</del> Found this out myself - just add or omit " const" at the end of the method signature.

Comment: I suggest making *#3* a different question - the last is Doxygen specific, while the former are general C++ questions. Seperating *#1* and *#2* might work better too.

Comment: #2 is just a special case of #1, where the object in question is the one pointed to by `this`. I definitely agree that #3 should have its own question, though.

Comment: @bcat: Well, thus *might* - the implementation sharing is an interesting issue on its own: [#1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/407100/calling-a-const-function-from-a-non-const-object), [#2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333849/how-to-generate-a-non-const-method-from-a-const-method), [#3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/856542/elegant-solution-to-duplicate-const-and-non-const-getters), ... :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know about doxygen; though here is what I know.

1. If there's only a non-`const` version, it simply can't be called on a `const` object.
2. If there's only a `const` version, it can be called on both `const` and non-`const` objects.
3. If there's both, the non-`const` version will be called on non-`const` objects, and the `const` version will be called on `const` objects.
4. If you want to explicitly call the `const` one, you have to cast your object to a const reference of itself: `static_cast<const MyClass&>(myObject).objectReference();`

Comment: Would you use `const_cast` instead?

Comment: @Duracell: I'd rather use `const_cast` only for removing the `const` modifier, since `static_cast` does a great job at adding it.

Comment: @Duracell @zneak:  This is a good use case for [an `implicit_cast` function template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/868306/what-is-the-difference-between-static-cast-and-implicit-cast/869597#869597).

Comment: A cast is unnecessary.  Best to use casts for narrowing conversions, adding `const` is a widening conversion.  Instead, just initialize a reference, as in `const MyClass& constmyObject = myObject; constmyObject.objectReference();`  This can't do anything unsafe by accident.

Comment: @Jake: James's suggestion of `implicit_cast` is a neatly wrapped way of expressing the initialize-a-const-reference method.  Only downside is an extra header file from boost.

Comment: For completeness it might be of interest that function pointers can also be used to differentiate the two: `(void (X::*)() const)&X::f;` - useful e.g. for disambiguating with `bind()` et al.

Answer (score 1):

While, calling the non-`const` method on a `const` instance probably isn't wise. If you want to call the `const` method on a non-`const` instance, however, just use a cast. See the following program for an example:

```
#include <iostream>

class ConstTest {
public:
  void cows() const {
    std::cout << "const method call" << std::endl;
  };

  void cows() {
    std::cout << "non-const method call" << std::endl;
  }
};

int main() {
  ConstTest ct;

  ct.cows();                                 // Prints "non-const method call"
  static_cast<const ConstTest &>(ct).cows(); // Prints "const method call"
}
```